# Meteor call Accounts.verifyEmail on server?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using Meteor, is it possible to call `Accounts.verifyEmail( token )` on the server? I want to verify a users email without logging them in. I have created a method and called it on the client as I have written above but it fails silently.

If there is a way to accomplish this from the client I would be interested to know this also.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your users to be logged in after submitting their token without having to override Meteor's methods, instead of calling `Accounts.verifyEmail( token )` in your route, you can call a method on the server which will confront the given token with the `services.email.verificationTokens` items. If one of them matches, you can then update the `verified` field of the email attached and then remove the token field from `services.email.verificationTokens`.

You should get from:

```
verificationTokens: [
 {
  token: '523uL7XUvlMji-yv48ErEAe8Fq2VvAuMf_oY8lJSPfJ',
  address: 'qwe@dew.dewee',
  when: Thu Dec 10 2015 19:00:52 GMT+0100 (CET)
 } 
]
```

to an empty array (given you had only one token to verify).

```
verificationTokens: []
```

Comment: Thanks @koOstik so the query should be something along the lines of Meteor.users.find({'services.email.verificationTokens': token})?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment until now. Yes, this should be something like this. I can edit with more details if you need.

Comment: Glad to hear this. Also it's good to keep in mind that since it's a Meteor's internal logic tweak, it might stop working if they change the way Meteor verifies emails,best to have a unit test around :)